# Casting object to its interface from a point of view of PHP

Tags: java, php, casting

I am trying to rewrite (for a educational reasons) Java code to PHP. It's in  this repository. My problem is [here](https://github.com/daniel-lobo/Sokoban/blob/master/src/backend/Box.java#L42) on line 42. We can see there the following code:

```
if (this.getBoard().getTile(boxNextPlace) instanceof ContentOperations && 
    ((ContentOperations)this.getBoard().getTile(boxNextPlace)).getContent() == null)
{
    ...
```

As first step we check if `this.getBoard().getTile(boxNextPlace)` returns object implementing [`ContentOperations`](https://github.com/daniel-lobo/Sokoban/blob/master/src/backend/ContentOperations.java) interface. If so, we go to step two, calling the `this.getBoard().getTile(boxNextPlace)` chain again, but this time we cast returned value to `ContentOperations` and then invoke the `getContent` method for further processing (in this case to compare it with null, `.getContent()==null` but this is irrelevant to my question).

As far as I understand casting in this case is some kind of protection from calling method not implemented by the object, but it is already proven by `this.getBoard().getTile(boxNextPlace) instanceof ContentOperations` condition, that object is of `ContentOperations` type.

So the question is: why is casting an object to its interface necessary if it is proven to be of the required type? Or maybe my understanding of this protective function of casting is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person who wrote the Java code does an `instanceof` check on line 42, but they neglect to do one again on line 55.  If `getTile()` really could return an object that isn't a `ContentOperations`, a `ClassCastException` would occur.  I would assume that you don't need any extra logic in PHP to account for a different return type.

Comment: I have also noticed that, but the confusing thing is the fact that though the the type of an object is confirmed, it is still being casted. Should I just assume casting in this case is irrelevant and is there for no reason?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would assume.  Do you have access to the person who wrote the Java code?

Comment: unfortunately not. Why is that? Maybe I would try to contact author in case of future uncertainty, but for now there is nothing I couldn't check with doc or ask on the net. Anyway, thanks for help!